# Ingnoring Labels in Grafana Chart

Tags: grafana, prometheus

Im using a Prometheus push gateway to send Metrics from a Cronjob to Prometheus and then displaying them in Grafana.

Some metric labels change over the course of multiple runs of the cronjob. Grafana shows these metrics with changed labels as seperate metrics. How do i combine the same metric with different label values into one metric? (One line shown in Grafana)

Answer (score -1):

> Some metric labels change over the course of multiple runs of the cronjob.

That's usually a bad idea for the reason you've discovered. I'd suggest fixing this on the cronjob side.

Comment: My idea was to use the changing labels to identify a state change in the cronjob's environment, in order to help with a drilldown in case of anomalies in the metric.

Could you suggest a different solution that would help me keep track of state changes that might affect the metric?

Comment: What sort of state changes? Could you represent it as a number?